# End of the page in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I am displaying records under a header.sometime the header is printing at the end of the page and remaining details are displaying in next page.

---

### page-1

### Customer-1

- Details-1
- Detials-2

---

### Customer-2

- Details-1
- Detials-2

But i am getting as below

### Page-1

### customer-1

- Details-1
- Details-2

---

### customer-2

### Page-2

- Details-1
- Detials-2

Only what i want is if header is printing at the end of the page then either i want to suppress it or move it to the next page. i better i suppress it.

Comment: I tried with Group Expert->Options-> Keep Group Together but it is splitting the each record to next page but i dont want that. i want to split the details but not header in one page and detials in another page.

Comment: So you want to prevent an orphaned group header at the bottom of the page but also not move new groups to a new page? That's a little tricky. Try method #2 from this [link](http://www.microassist.com/tips/crystal-reports-prevent-orphaned-group-header)

Answer (score 0):

Take header to new page everytime using the option `new page after`

---

Edit: do one thing use the header in `page header` and try to supress the group header at the start of every page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. yes but as per requirement we dont want to display each details in one page we need to continuous the printing. while doing this i am getting the header only in bottom of one page and remaining details are going to next page. Is there any way to find out the end of page? like finding the end record with (ONLastRecord()).